Skipping terms in recursive sequence
If I have a recursive sequence ($a_1=1$):
$$
\begin{align}
a_{2n}&=ba_n\\
a_{2n+1}&=a_n-ca_{n+1}\\\\
\implies\underset{:=\textbf{A}}{\begin{pmatrix}b & 0\\ 1 & -c\end{pmatrix}}\begin{pmatrix}a_n\\a_{n+1}\end{pmatrix}&= \begin{pmatrix}a_{2n}\\a_{2n+1}\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
$$
So trying to use the standard trick with eigenvalues/diagonalisation:
$$\begin{align}\textbf{A} \begin{pmatrix}a_1\\a_{2}\end{pmatrix}&=\textbf{A} \begin{pmatrix}a_2\\a_3\end{pmatrix}\\\\\textbf{A} \begin{pmatrix}a_2\\a_{3}\end{pmatrix}&=\textbf{A} \begin{pmatrix}a_4\\a_{5}\end{pmatrix}\end{align}$$
Going well so far, but on the next one something happens:
$$\textbf{A} \begin{pmatrix}a_4\\a_{5}\end{pmatrix} =\textbf{A} \begin{pmatrix}a_8\\a_{9}\end{pmatrix} $$
Notice the terms $a_6$ and $a_7$ are missing. One way I can see to reconcile this is to compute $\textbf{A} \begin{pmatrix}a_3\\a_{4}\end{pmatrix} $, but I’m struggling to visualise how to know when vectors are “left out” of one of these series. If I want all terms of $a_n$ below $N$, is there a way to see how many of these “starting vectors” I need? Is this even the right way to think about this problem?

The standard trick was developed for $a_{n+1}=a_n+a_{n-1}$ and the like. There is a subtle, but profound difference between $n+1$ and $2n$. If you repeatedly step from $n$ to $n+1$, you will cover all natural numbers without missing any. Not so with $2n$.

@IvanNeretin yes, this works quite well for the fibonacci sequence etc. Should a completely different technique be used in this case then?

Why? Like you just said, you combine (a3,  a4) to get (a6, a7), and so on. You still get all terms, only not in a sequential fashion.

If you are writing a program to do this, you should probably just allocate an array and loop through it, assigning to each index the computed recurrence relation using the previous elements of the array.
